# How to specify floating point decimal precision from variable?

Tags: python, string, floating-point, floating-point-precision

I have the following repetitive simple code repeated several times that I would like to make a function for:

```
for i in range(10):
    id  = "some id string looked up in dict"
    val = 63.4568900932840928 # some floating point number in dict corresponding to "id"
    tabStr += '%-15s = %6.1f\n' % (id,val)
```

I want to be able to call this function: `def printStr(precision)`
Where it preforms the code above and returns `tabStr` with `val` to `precision` decimal points.

For example: `printStr(3)`
would return `63.457` for `val` in `tabStr`.

Any ideas how to accomplish this kind of functionality?

Answer (score 47):

```
tabStr += '%-15s = %6.*f\n' % (id, i, val)
```

where `i` is the number of decimal places.

---

BTW, in the recent Python where `.format()` has superseded `%`, you could use

```
"{0:<15} = {2:6.{1}f}".format(id, i, val)
```

for the same task.

Or, with field names for clarity:

```
"{id:<15} = {val:6.{i}f}".format(id=id, i=i, val=val)
```

If you are using Python 3.6+, you could simply use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals):

```
f"{id:<15} = {val:6.{i}f}"
```

Answer (score 15):

I know this an old thread, but there is a much simpler way to do this:

Try this:

```
def printStr(FloatNumber, Precision):
    return "%0.*f" % (Precision, FloatNumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work too

```
tabStr += '%-15s = ' % id + str(round(val, i))
```

where `i` is the precision required.

Answer (score 0):

Tested in Python 3.8 and 3.9:

```
>>> val = 1.123456789
>>> decimals = 3
>>> f"{val:0.{decimals}f}"
'1.123'
```

Comment: This solution has already been given.